# Xamarin iOS - unable to archive. Missing dll.msym file on unzipping

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am able to deploy my app to physical device both on Release and Debug configuration.

Unfortunately, when I try to archive build for iOS I get an error:

> **Cannot create iOS archive. Process cannot be executed on XMA server.**
>
> **There was an error unzipping the file** D:\Xamarin..\2022-04-17\475a5340.zip:
> **Could not find a part of the path** 'C.:\Users..\Xamarin\Extractions\af36ba21-caa2-451b-8617-82a6620d3cc7\bundlename.PM.xcarchive\bundlename.i0S.app.mSYM\82259147a6b6adO7c61d517ae1e37f6b***Microsoft.Extensions.DependencylnjectionAbstractions.dll.msym***

.msym files for other dlls seem to be fine in other folders.
The issue appear after my all-round update: VS on Windows, X-code, Mono and Xamarin.iOS SDK on Mac. I use VS 2022 17.1.4

What I've tried:

1. Adding nuget package reference with this library to all my projects
2. removing reference to this library in all my projects
3. deleting bin-obj\cleaning\rebuilding
4. changing archive directory for xamarion iOS in VisualStudio settings
5. setting long file names in Windows Regedit

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is currently being investigated:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Xamarin-iOS-project-wont-archive-anymor/1587820

You can resolve this issue on your machine by building from the command line,please refer to:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Xamarin-iOS-project-wont-archive-anymor/1587820#T-N10008135

Comment: I've tried changing it, as I mentioned in the post. This is not a "name too long" error I got here, unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for your response.Please see my update.

Comment: Thanks! After several attempts I was able to make ipa-file through Developer Console with the help of your workaround. Though it is pretty painful temporary way of distribution and I'm still looking for more comprehensive solution.

Comment: Marking this as an answer, but in fact it is pretty painful workaround.  I'll post solution here when I find it

Comment: Thanks for your update.I'll also update U if there's an elegant workaround for you!